# How to: Custom Prevent Caching?

Tags: html, xhtml

After symcbean's answer I decided to change my question to:

What's the correct way to keep cache of images/css/js only? Html will not be cached in any web browser.

Comment: Doesn't sending those headers as real headers for the html pages work?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Those HTML headers (or the HTTP header suggested by the others) should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go read some good books on the topic - or the specs. You're currently very badly informed.

> A normal "trick" is to use:

Normal for whom? Setting Pragma: no-cache has *nothing to do with what the browser caches*. Setting Expires to -1 should prevent the current document from being cached - but its an HTTP/1.0 ONLY attribute - HTTP/1.1 has been in widespread use for the past 8 years.

> However this is a very expensive decision. The cost is to retrieve all the images, css and javascript files in every request

No - the example you've given is an HTML tag - which can **only** occur in an HTML file. By default (i.e. in the absence of any specific caching directions) browsers "MAY" use cached file - in my experience, its only some mobile devices which cache so aggressively - but none of them implement the requirement to warn the user about this (see rfc 2616 13.1.5).

Caching instructions (and indeed all meta-data) should be sent in the HTTP headers - the META tags provide a surrogate mechanism in some cases.

Have a google for Mark Nottingham's caching tutorial - its a good starting point - but only a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Configure your server to send the `Pragma: no-cache` and `Expires: ...` headers with html content. its trivial to do with apache in a `.htaccess` just add a `files` section with a pattern that matches any `.html` file and set the headers there using [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) or better yet `mod_expires`